# Optimized 2D convolution library in C for CPU

Tags: python, cpu, vectorization, convolution

I am doing convolutions with a large amount of small images (36*36 or so) and small filters (3*3 to 5*5). So an [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)-based solution is not what I am looking for. Perhaps a highly optimized and tuned implementation (with [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)/[AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions), multithreading) is better for me.

However, convolution is not included in [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms). And FFT libraries (FFTW) do not have a convolution function. I tried *scipy.signal.convolve2d*, and it is even slower than my naive C implementation.

Is there a dedicated convolution library optimized for small kernels on CPU? It will be better if it automatically switches to FFT on large kernels.

I am coding in Python, but a C/C++ library is OK as long as I can import it with *ctypes*. My GPU is too old to give any speedup.

Related questions:

- *[Fast 2D convolution implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222725/fast-2d-convolution-implementation)*
- *[Fast way to implement 2D convolution in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676709/fast-way-to-implement-2d-convolution-in-c)*
- *[Fastest 2D convolution or image filter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710842/fastest-2d-convolution-or-image-filter-in-python)*

They are all talking about FFT, but not vectorization.